# Regex validation to only allow closing parenthesis when matched by an opening parenthesis

Tags: c#, regex

I'm a total newbie when it comes to regex validation. My goal is to validate a string the user inputs using the following conditions:

1. The string may or may not be enclosed in a parenthesis.
2. A closing parenthesis is only allowed at the end of the string.
3. An opening parenthesis is only allowed at the start of the string.
4. An opening parenthesis is only allowed when there is a closing parenthesis at the end.
5. A closing parenthesis is only allowed when there is an opening parenthesis at the start of the string.

**Below are samples of valid string:**

```
anytexthere
(anytexthere)
```

**Invalid strings:**

```
(anytexthere
anytexthere)
any(texthere)
(anytext)here
any(texthere
any)texthere
any()texthere
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm really starting to wonder if this is possible by just using a single regex.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do it with a [conditional](http://www.regular-expressions.info/conditional.html):

```
if (Regex.IsMatch(subject, 
    @"^    # Start of string
    (      # Match and capture into group 1:
     \(    # an opening parenthesis
    )?     # optionally.
    [^()]* # Match any number of characters except parentheses
    (?(1)  # Match (but only if capturing group 1 participated in the match)
     \)    # a closing parenthesis.
    )      # End of conditional
    $      # End of string", 
    RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace)) {
    // Successful match
}
```

Or, of course, since there are only two ways a string can match:

```
if (Regex.IsMatch(subject, 
    @"^     # Start of string
    (?:     # Either match
     \(     # an opening parenthesis,
     [^()]* # followed by any number of non-parenthesis characters
     \)     # and a closing parenthesis
    |       # or
     [^()]* # match a string that consists only of non-parens characters
    )       # End of alternation
    $       # End of string", 
    RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace))
```